# HTML form with 3 submits, But JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am writing the BBCodes part to my forums so I have three submit buttons: one for the color picker, one for inserting a typed url and one to actually post the forum.

I am using button with onclick: the url and color picker use a submit button in insert the text into the textarea and the final submit posts the form. When pressing the final submit the following error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

p.s. I have removed the majority of the 's for the simple BBCodes to lessen the amount of code under html.

note: I have another posting class similar to this that hasn't had the bbcodes added yet and the javascript for posting the form works perfectly fine - hence my guess that the 3 submit buttons are causing this.

html:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="get" name="postingTopicSub" id="postingTopicSub" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="topicID" id="topicID" value="<?php echo $topicID ?>"/>

    <div class="post-subject">
        Subject:
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />
    </div>

    <div class="post-addons">
        <input type="button" class="bbc_button" name="color" value="Choose a Font Color" onclick="bbstylecolor()" title="Font color: [color=red]text[/color] or [color=#FF0000]text[/color]">
        <div id="colour_palette" style="display:none;">
            <br>
            <input type="color" id="color" value="#ff0000">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Pick" onclick="bbcolor();">
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="bbc-button" name="bbcode1" value=" " style="background-image:url('../images/BBC/bold.gif');" onclick="bbstyle(1);" title="Bold Text: [b]text[/b]">
        <input type="button" class="bbc_button" name="bburl" value=" " style="background-image:url('../images/BBC/url.gif');" onclick="bburl();" title="List item: [url]http://url[/url] or [url=http://url]text[/url]">
        <div class="urlforms" id="url_div" style="display:none;">
            <br>
            <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <tr>
            <td>Enter a site URL:</td>
            <td width="200px";><input type="text" id="url_input" placeholder="http://themooliecommunity.com/"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Optional description:</td> 
            <td width="200px";><input type="text" id="url_input_title" placeholder="The Moolie Community"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Insert into message" onclick="bburlpick();">
            <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Exit" onclick="bburl();">
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="bbc_button" name="bbcode14" value=" " style="background-image:url('../images/BBC/spoil.gif');" onclick="bbstyle(14);" title="Spoiler: [spoil]Text[/spoil]">
    </div>

    <div class="post-textarea">
        <textarea name="post_text" id="post_text" cols="100" rows="30"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="post-button">
        <input type="button" name="submittopic" id = "submittopic" value="Submit" onclick="topicPostSubmit();"/> 
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

Javascript:

Final submit button:

```
function forumssubmit() 
{
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var text = document.getElementById("post_text").value;

   if(subject=="" || text=="")
   {
       alert('Please fill in the subject and text');
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function topicPostSubmit()
{
  if(forumssubmit())
  {
    document.getElementById("postingTopicSub").submit(); //This is where the error is coming
  }
}
```

URL submit button js:

```
function bburlpick() 
{
    var e = document.getElementById("url_div");
    var text = document.getElementById("post_text").value;
    var url = document.getElementById("url_input").value;
    var url_title = document.getElementById("url_input_title").value;

    if (url_title == "")
    {
        var bburl = "[url]" + url + "[/url]";
    }
    else
    {
        var bburl = "[url=" + url + "]" + url_title + "[/url]";
    }
    text += bburl;
    document.getElementById("post_text").value = text;
    document.getElementById("post_text").focus();
    e.style.display = "none";
}
```

Color submit button:

```
function bbcolor() 
{
    var text = document.getElementById("post_text").value;
    var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    var bbcolor = "[color=" + color + "][/color]";
    text += bbcolor;
    document.getElementById("post_text").value = text;
    document.getElementById("post_text").focus();
}
```

Comment: There's no element with the ID `postingTopicSub`. So, `document.getElementById("postingTopicSub")` is `null`, and you can't call `submit` on `null`. Other than that, you shouldn't put `{` in separate lines due to [ASI](http://www.2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html). This is likely to cause breakage in the future.

Comment: @Chiru, there is, first line of code, gotta scroll to it

Comment: you have a button with "name" property 'submit". Change the name of the button and your code should work

Comment: Matt, try looking at [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml) page, it could help you

Comment: @ElenaDBA, the name should not matter, the OP is using `getElementById`...

Comment: Can you tell, where JS code is? Above or below the form?

Comment: Try my suggestion and you will see. It's a pretty common issue. Change  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Pick" onclick="bbcolor();">  to  <input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Pick" onclick="bbcolor();">

Comment: @SamSwift웃 In the code, there might be; but certainly not in the DOM. It's probably due to misplacement of the `<script>` tag, I reckon. Always move scripts down before `</body>`, especially if you're trying to do DOM manipulations.

Comment: "submit is not a function" means that you named your submit button or some other element submit. Rename the button to btnSubmit and your call will work. Just make sure you re-name all the buttons named "submit", you have quite a few.  Check this out:  http://www.chovy.com/javascript/javascript-error-submit-is-not-a-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Pick" onclick="bbcolor();">
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Pick" onclick="bbcolor();">
```

The issue is that your button is named "submit"

"submit is not a function" means that you named your submit button or some other element submit. Rename the button to btnSubmit and your call will work. Just make sure you re-name all the buttons named "submit", you have quite a few.

Check this out: 
http://www.chovy.com/javascript/javascript-error-submit-is-not-a-function/

Comment: Didn't realise that the name submit and .submit would clash. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have named your other buttons in the same form as `submit` so the error is instead of getting `.submit()` it is getting reference to `submit button` of course those are not `function` so try renaming them to something different and then try